# Automating IF statements

Tags: php, if-statement

I am working on page where are multiple variants of same product. I'm using if statements to check if there is some change to show. However, as you can see I am repeating pretty much the same thing with if statements. How can I automate multiple if statements to a one?

Something like this:

```
if($s->??? !=0 ) {
    product->??? = $s->???;
}
```

My code:

```
while ($s = $subProduct->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

    $product->variant = $s->variant;

    if ($s->price != 0) {
        $product->price = $s->price;
    }
    if ($s->battery != 0) {
        $product->battery = $s->battery;
    }
    if ($s->topspeed != 0) {
        $product->topspeed = $s->topspeed;
    }
    if ($s->range != 0) {
        $product->range = $s->range;
    }
}
```

Comment: where does $r comes from? I only see $s variable initiated here?

Comment: @AbdulRahmanASamad Sorry, that was a mistake. Only $s should be there. Corrected.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Just copying properties from one object to another doesn't seem to make a lot of sense, using something like `$product = $subProduct->fetchObject(YOUR_PRODUCT_CLASS)` seems more what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php).

```
$vars = get_object_vars($s);
foreach($vars as $key => $value) {
    if($s->$key != 0) 
        $product->$key = $s->$key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm sure that there are plenty of options, but just to maybe give you an idea:

```
$optionalParams = array("range","topspeed","price","battery");
foreach($optionalParams as $option) { 
 if(isset($s->$option) && $s->$option != 0)
  $product->$option = $s->$option;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5 you can just use [object iteration](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)

just by doing that

```
foreach ($v as $key => $prop){
    if ($prop != 0){
        $v->$key = $s->battery;
    }
}
```

Full code example

```
<?php
$v= new \stdClass();
$v->name = "john";
$v->age = 30;

foreach ($v as $key => $prop){
    if ($prop){
        $v->$key = "changed";
    }
}
var_dump($v);
exit;
```

Now, all `$v` properties is "changed"

See the code as demo (https://eval.in/833456)